# Tikz: Draw simple shortened curved line between two coordinates in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm creating an overlay to a picture. The picture has several objects and I want to draw arrows between them. I only have the coordinates and not the sizes so I must offset the arrows as not to overlap the objects.

Here is the image to use. Try to create an arrow, similar to the yellow curved line, to the black circle from the green circle.

[image: Arrows]

I would like to "shorten" the arrows by giving a length that it offsets from both ends. (so 0cm would start and stop the arrow at the endpoints and 0.1cm will start it 0.1cm and stop it at 0.1cm) I would also like to set a curvature amount like "0.4" that will curve the arrow some amount. (0 = straight, 1 = maximum curvature possible)

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] at (0,0) {\includegraphics{hnRDQ.png}};
\coordinate (G) at (2.3,6.1);
\coordinate (R) at (6.4,3.9);
\coordinate (B) at (2.1,1.7);
\draw [green] (G) -- (R);
\draw [red]   (R) -- (B);
\draw [black] (B) -- (G);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

(the coordinates are only approximate)

Clarify:

I want to basically specify the radius of curvature of the "arc". So, instead of having to specify the angle in and the angle out I want to specify one number. The in and out angles should be easily computed from the radius of curvature...

Basically I would like to do something like `\draw (A) [arc=0.5] (B);` And it draws a 3 point arc with the 3rd point being on the radius of curvature, the 0.5 specifying out far out.

Comment: I don't get the question completely but are you looking for `\draw [black,shorten <=1cm,shorten >=1cm] (B) -- (G);`?

Comment: Combine both answers and percusse's comment and you might see the difference between `\draw (some node 1) -- (some node 2);` and `\draw (some coordinate 1) -- (some coordinate 2);` where in the last example nodes are drawn _at_ those coordinates. For your use case (what I can see from your picture) I recommend re-drawing those circles (as nodes).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel The picture is only an example, mine is much more complex and doesn't even have circles. What if it was a horse and a pig and you wanted to draw a line between one and the other?

Comment: @JonSlaughter There is `\draw (a) arc[radius=1cm, start angle=<alpha>, end angle=<beta>];` where `<alpha>` and `<beta>` are arbitrary angles (there's also `delta angle`). For a less manual way, I think [`tkz-euclide`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tkz-euclide)can help here (especially the multi-functional `\tkzDrawArc`).

Comment: For the `to`-path keys `out` and `in` does also exist the `looseness` key that kind of works like your `arc=0.5` specification would ([PGF/TikZ manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf), section 51.3 “Curves”, pp. 469ff.).

Comment: With your last request, `arc=0.5` gives two possibilities: left and right...

Comment: Always with your last request, how to draw an arc if no solution exists with the specified value of `arc` (radius of curvature) ?

Comment: @PaulGaborit Only 1, you can use a negative value to represent the other side. A solution will always exist. One can draw an infinite number of circles intersecting two points. The parameter just selects one. (it's not the same as drawing a circle between 3 arbitrary points, which still, always has a solution)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Yes, it is sort of like it but mine is more specific, always producing an arc. Looseness may or may not work though, I'll play around with it.

Comment: @JonSlaughter If the radius of curvature is less than half the distance between A and B, there is no solution ...

Comment: @PaulGaborit I've give the math for the radius of curvature depending on a single parameter $\rho$. To get the center of the circle one needs to shift the vector.

Answer (score 62):

I am also not 100% sure about the question, but hope this addresses the various parts I see.

Here is an example of a straight line, a curved line, and a shortened curved line (in violet):

[image]

### 1. Draw Straight Line:

```
\draw  (G) -- (R)
```

produces the straight olive line from `(G)` to `(R)`.

### 2. Curved Line:

```
\draw    (R) to[out=-20,in=-70] (B)
```

produces the red line with curvature.  Instead of using `--`, we use the `to` syntax, and the options `out=` specifies the angle at the start point, and the `in=` specifies the angle at the end point.

Using `distance=3cm` with the same `in=`, and `out=` we get the red dotted line.

### 3. Shortened Line:

Withe either of the straight or curved lines, one can use `shorten <=` to shorten the start point or `shorten >=` to shorten the end point.  A shorten of `0.25cm` is applied to both ends of the violet line.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[ultra thick]
\coordinate (G) at (2.3,6.1);
\coordinate (R) at (6.4,3.9);
\coordinate (B) at (2.1,1.7);

\node [fill=green,circle] at (G) {}; 
\node [fill=red,  circle] at (R) {};
\node [fill=blue, circle] at (B) {};

\draw [olive, -] (G) -- (R);
\draw [red]   (R) to[out=-20,in=-70] (B);
\draw [red,dotted]   (R) to[out=-20,in=-70, distance=3cm ] (B);
\draw [violet, ->, shorten <= 0.25cm, shorten >= 0.25cm] (B) to[out=120,in=150] (G);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Basically I want to use special values for in and out. Draw a 3 point arc with 2 points being the two coordinates/nodes. The 3rd point is a line midway in between the two points and tangent to the line connecting the nodes. The radius of curvature then specifies how curved the arc is.

Comment: Sorry, but I am still not following.  It would recommend that you illustrate what you describe with code. So, edit the question and include a manually crafted example of what you describe above.  Make it clear what is provided, and what is being determined.  You can for instance take my example, and replace all the `\draw` commands with something that shows your desired syntax (commented out as it won't work yet), and the code that that syntax should be equivalent to.

Answer (score 24):

I don't also know if I am understanding your question right. But instead of specifying the amount of bend by length, you can specify it by angle as in my answer.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line/.style={<->,shorten >=0.4cm,shorten <=0.4cm},thick]
%\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] at (0,0) {\includegraphics{hnRDQ.png}};
\node (G) [circle,draw,inner sep=0pt,minimum width=2cm]  at (2.3,6.1) {};
\node (R) [circle,draw,inner sep=0pt,minimum width=1.5cm] at (6.4,3.9) {};
\node (B) [circle,draw,inner sep=0pt,minimum width=1cm] at (2.1,1.7) {};
\path [green,line,bend left] (G) edge (R);
\path [red,bend left,line]   (R) edge (B);
\path [black,line,out=135,in=225] (B) edge (G); % you can control the bend by manually specifying in=<angle> and out=<angle> options
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]